# Apache is not starting After upgrading PHP 7.0.9 to PHP 7.0.30 in XAMPP

Tags: xampp, php-7

Right now, my xampp has php 7.0.9 version. Now, I want to upgrade it to php 7.0.30. So, as per guidelines and tutorials shared on internet, I have download thread safe 64 bit php 7.0.30 from below URL:

[Downloaded PHP 7.0.30 from Here](https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.0)

And put this folder into xampp folder. After this, I have updated xampp configuration file.

After doing all of the above steps, when I am trying to restart/start apache it is not starting and showing me below error:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
5:47:27 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
5:47:27 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
5:47:27 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:47:27 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:47:27 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
5:47:27 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

I have also tried to start Apache even after shutting down my SKYPE but still not starting.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading from php.net I've had better luck downloading the portable version of XAMPP directly from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.0.30/). You can then take the php directory from the downloaded zip and (after renaming your current php directory) copy it into the xampp directory.

I found that I also had to copy over the ng2http2.dll and libssh2.dll from the (new) php directory to the xampp/apache/bin directory (again after renaming old files).

After a quick check of the new php.ini file and starting the XAMPP server, my local sites loaded the new version.

The above worked for me upgrading from PHP 7.0.x to 7.1.x on Windows 10.